# How do I run Python script from a subdirectory?

Tags: python, import, module, terminal, directory

I want to be able to write a line of code like this and have it run smoothly:

```
python /path/to/python_file.py -arg1 -arg2 -etc
```

I figured out an easy way to discover all modules and add them to the current Python path, but it still doesn't seem to recognize the .py file, even though it's supposedly in the `sys.path`. I know the `sys.path` addition is working because I can perform this in the interpreter just fine:

```
>>>import ModuleManager # My Python script to discover modules in lower directories
>>>import testModule # Module I want to run from lower directory
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named testModule

>>>ModuleManager.discoverModules() # Now, I find the modules and add them to path
Discovering Modules...Complete!
Discovered 6 Modules.
>>>import testModule # No error now.
>>>
```

What I would like to do at this point is be able to go into my terminal and say:

```
python testModule -arg1 -arg2 -etc
```

and have it perform how I would expect.

To be clear, I want to write a line of code in `ModuleManager.py` (from my application root folder) that allows me to access a file named `testModule.py` which is found in `/root/path/to/testModule.py` in a way such that I can use arguments as in `python testModule.py -arg1 -arg2 -etc`. Any suggestions?

Comment: Where you launch the `python` interpreter from becomes your current working directory. If the file in/your/path is a self-contained script then what you want to do is `cd` there first then execute. If the script fits within the larger project you want to make your file-structure into a module. Then you can `python -m project.utils.script` -- If you want to stick with your original, try putting a `./path` (dot) in-front of your path to ensure proper relative references.

Comment: Again, I want to be able to use the file AS IF it's in the current path, when it is NOT in the current path. I need to be able to call it as terminal command (with arguments), not as a regular module (with functions).

Comment: You need to restructure the folders into a module format and then try relative imports. `from .. import testModule`

Comment: Well, first off, relative imports are generally thought of as a no-no in Python (see [PEP 328](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328)). But aside from that, it doesn't solve my problem. My problem is that I want to be able to add a relative directory to my current Python path WITHIN my python script so that I can run the file AS IF it is in my current path. I want to be able to use system arguments.

Comment: The title for this question is misleading as OP is asking about running scripts, not necessarily about file organization and package/module management as the title implies

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## How to call from Python another Python script

You want to call a Python script, which works well only if run from particular directory as it has some imports which work well only from given location.

Assuming there is a subdirectory named "script_dir" and there is the "local_script_name.py" file:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["python", "local_script_name.py"], cwd="script_dir")
```

If your script accepts command line arguments "arg1", "arg2", "-etc"

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["python", "local_script_name.py", "arg1", "arg2", "-etc"], cwd="script_dir")
```

Comment: Very cool. I am currently using `subprocess` to run my terminal commands! The problem is that my user will be not be able to specify where the directory is, the solution needs to be more robust and to find or "discover" arbitrary Python modules and add them to the current usable commands. Basically, the user should be able to run my script and use Python modules as if they were Shell commands. In other words, if I had a module named `runMe.py` that was located in `/path/to/runMe.py`, I want the user to be able to say `python runMe.py -arg1 -arg2` and not be concerned with its location.

Comment: @Blairg23 You mentioned, you know, how to discover the files to call. If you have file name, than use `os.path` functions to split directory and base file name.

Comment: Ah, very good! I didn't even think of that! The only problem I find is that right now, the script the user runs does not know whether or not the item is a module or a regular terminal command and I would like to keep it that way.... my `ModuleManager.py` script does all the discovering and adding to path for easy importing, but it has no way to tell the main script `subprocess` command to use the `cwd="script_dir"` parameter. Can you think of a work-around? Honestly, adding all the subdirectories to the path would be ideal.

Comment: @Blairg23 If you manage importing that file, try `__path__` to learn, where it lives

Comment: Correct, but the main problem I'm having isn't being able to import the file. I'm not trying to import the file whatsoever. I simply want to be able to run it. I want the main script to do the following: 1) discover all subdirectory modules (without importation) and 2) run them like terminal commands with arguments. The problem is, I don't want to import all of the modules I discover (since most of them are modules that are in the main directory and don't need special importation). Once I discover them, I want to assume they all are in the same directory. Meanwhile, I want them organized.

Comment: I would just put them in the same directory which would solve all my problems, but I want to organize them in subdirectories for the human users. I want something to the effect of `/tools/networking/net_tool.py` and `/tools/audio/audio_tool.py`, etc. for easy organization. But in the end, I want the main script to not know the difference between a module and a regular terminal command. Therefore, the main script doesn't do anything aside from running strings, which it assumes are legal terminal commands.

Answer (score 11):

`sys.path.append(os.getcwd())` work for me. 
Now you can run commands like `./manage/my_cli_command.py`

Answer (score 9):

## How to write python scripts efficiently

There are multiple ways to write Python script (a script, which is supposed to be called from command line).

For flexible use, forget about manipulating `PYTHONPATH` - such solutions are difficult to maintain and re rather shaky.

### Script with Python stdlib imports only

Betting purely on packages and modules, which are part of Python stdlib makes the script easy to run from anywhere.

Extension to this is importing modules and packages, which are globally installed. Globally installing packages is mostly considered bad practice, as it spoils global Python environment. I have globally installed just small set of packages, which I use often: `pyyaml`, `docopt`, `lxml`, `jinja2`.

### Script importing any installed package

Packages and modules, even your own, can be installed by means of `setup.py`. It took me a while to get used to this, I was initially ignoring `setup.py` as too complex solution, but later on I used to use it for any home-made package which I need to import in my programs.

#### Importing packages installed into virtualenv

This is by far my most popular solution now.

You will need your packages having `setup.py`.

After virtualenv is created, you use `pip` to install all the packages you need.

With given virtualenv being active, you can than simply use the script, which will see the packages available for import regardless of where you are your script starting from.

## Script installed by means of `setup.py`

Again, this solution seems first too complex "just for simple script", but finally it can become the simplest method.

You have to create simple Python project with your script and `setup.py` only. The `setup.py` shall declare the script for installing. There are two methods, either by `scripts` argument, or by `entry_points`, later one being more flexible - use that one.

The script is best installed from within virtualenv - after the installation is complete, find location of the script and move it whenever you want to use it. For using the script, there is no need to activate the virtualenv, it is enough to have it in PATH. The script inside includes refernces to Python from given virtualenv and this ensures, it uses it including all installed packages.

Note, that the best solution for having required packages installed for your script is mentioning it in `install_requires` argument in `setup.py`, it ensures, they get installed with your script automatically.

## Using `zc.buildout`

`zc.buildout` used to be my favourite solution until `pip` and `virtualenv` became mature solutions.

You have to create `buildout.cfg` file and there you define all what is needed for your script. this moslty includes having the `setup.py` in place, but this is not always necessary.

Personally, I found `zc.buildout` powerfull, but rather difficult to learn and I would recommend using `virtualenv` solution.

## Using other solutions like `PyInstaller`

There are other solution, which allow turning Python script into single executable file.

`PyInstaller` looks like good way to go. There might be other similar solutions.

## Conclusions

Forget about making your modules and packages importable by manipulating `PYTHONPATH`, such solutions are quite shaky.

My recommendation is to go for project having `setup.py` using `entry_points` to install your script.

Installation into virtualenv seems to be the cleanest method.

Setting up this environment (the project) the first time takes some effort, but after that, you can simply copy and adopt the solution and it will become natural way to go.

Comment: I need this to be able to run from a folder that will be moved to different computers every time. It is to run simple test scripts, but I have my test scripts in different folders and need to be run as terminal commands with command line arguments. I don't want to have to install anything, I want it to work "as-is" with the default Python libraries. Can this accomplish that in one or two lines of code?

Comment: @Blairg23 I misunderstood your question. New answer added (as another answer).

Answer (score 0):

Append the parent directory temporarily to the path:

`sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), os.path.pardir)))`